# how to move an element in a grid from one section to another

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

In a section that uses `display: grid;`, I want to move an element (button) from one grid section to another.

```html
<form>
    <div class="item-1">
        <span>телефон</span>
        <img src="Line 4.svg" width="327 px" height="2 px">
        <input type="text" id="phone">
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
        <span>имя</span>
        <img src="Line 4.svg" width="327 px" height="2 px">
        <input type="text" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="item-3">
        <span>класс</span>
        <img src="Line 4.svg" width="327 px" height="2 px">
        <input type="text" id="class">
    </div>
    <div class="application-button">
        <input type="button" id="send-button" value="Оставить заявку">
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: Button]

I haven't tried anything, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: This cannot be achieved nicely without using JavaScript (or some other way of fiddling with the content dynamically after the content has been rendered. 

HTML (what you've posted) is static. So moving elements around the markup, cannot be done with HTML. 

The good question is: When do you need the button to be moved?  
... is it one someone clicks a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by searching *grid-column-start* and *grid-column-end*.

Now you have that button like this:

```
#send-button {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
}
```

and you just need to change it to

```
grid-column-start: 3;
grid-column-end: 4;
```

(this is just static placement, of course. As Zeth said, if you want to change it dynamically, you'll need javascript or some library, etc..)